# Simplify Double Summation with interdependencies

Tags: summation

I'm trying to understand the worst-case time complexity of the kth permutation coding problem. That is, how do I simplify the following:

$$
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-l} 2l+m
$$

to

$$
\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(3m+2n+4)
$$

Comment: Should the inner sum be indexed by $m$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson It appears no, if that's the answer he's going for.

Comment: Correct the inner sum is indexed by i.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha was able to come up with this solution as well. I'm just not clear on how to get there.